# How to control amount of recursion in list.dirs?

Tags: r, directory, filesystems

For example, if in my current working directory `"."` I have subdirectories like:

```
./2013/1/1
./2013/1/5
...
./2013/1/29
./2013/2/2
...
./2013/2/28
...
./2013/12/31
./2014/01/01
...
```

That is, the structure is year subdirectory, followed by month subdirectory, then day subdirectory, possible with directories missing. How do I get `list.dirs` (with `recursion = TRUE`) to only return subdirectories up to the month level, e.g.:

```
./2013/1
./2013/2
...
./2013/12
./2014/01
...
```

Comment: You could just get all the results then filter out the ones with too many `/`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fleshing out dww's suggestion, you could list all directories recursively and then filter for those with two levels:

```
dirs <- list.dirs("datedirs", recursive = TRUE)

nlevels <- lapply(strsplit(dirs, .Platform$file.sep), length)

dirs[nlevels == 2]
```